# Commenting out System.out.println

Tags: java, blackberry

Do System.out.println(...) calls pose any effect if left in BlackBerry code or any other programming language?

When removed, the compilation time may be reduced, but is there any particular other reason to remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to know before using `System.out.println()` on Blackberry:

1. Once you print out something to the standard output any person that has your application installed on the device will be able to see them. All they need to do is to attach the device to the simulator and run in debug mode. So make sure you do not print out anything sensitive such as passwords, class names etc. in the released application.
2. The performance overhead that the `System.out.println()` itself makes is minimal, especially when the output stream is not attached to anything (i.e. Device is not connected and not in debug mode).

I myself rather use Blackberry preprocessor to be able to disable all logs before making a release. For this reason I define a logging directive `LOGGING` and then in my code:

```
//#ifdef LOGGING
System.out.println("LOGGING is enabled");
//#endif
```

For more on how to use preprocessors in Blackberry Eclipse plugin see [this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21065/Create_project_preprocessor_directives_927627_11.jsp).

Comment: better to wrap that in a method :) a method call is trivial but having to type the ifdef's all the time is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use a flag to disable sysouts. Sysouts are really slow if you use them a lot, eg. in loops.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime might be also reduced, as the statements are actually executed - even if the user doesn't see the output on the screen. If you're using a lot of these (e.g. in tight loops) or you're passing to them Objects with expensive toString() methods, the useless output may be slowing you down.

Also, if you're passing `String` as an argument, those will take some space in bytecode and in memory. You on your souped-up machine with 173 PB of RAM may not care, but there are resource-constrained systems (such as mobile devices).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't intend to use the output for anything like debugging ect. then it's best to take it out. Your program will only run as fast as the line can be output so in theory the less system.out line you have the faster the process will be.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Ant to preprocess these lines out of your source code. (Make sure that none of them have side-effects!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifically about Blackberry, but if your program is writing to an unknown device (i.e. you are not sure where standard out is going), there may be a potential for your app to occasionally/sporadically/inexplicably block momentarily in the attempt to write.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own method, i.e. :

```
public static void consoleMessage(String msg){
  if(DEBUG_FLAG){
    System.out.println(msg);
  }
}
```

Then use only this throughout your code. It will save you the time for changing all the lines.

Comment: But, you will still have a method call, I don't know how expensive this is on blackberry jvm.

Comment: Method calls should be very cheap (unless the JVM is totally braindead). If `DEBUG_FLAG` is `static final` then there's a good chance the compiler will optimise away the whole call. There will still be the cost of constructing `msg` which may be large if you do something like `consoleMessage(doSomethingSlow())` but probably isn't an issue in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like Log4J instead of system out print statements, it gives you much more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

Keeping `System.out` statements isn't that bad a thing to do usually. Users might be able to see them so it doesnt always look good in a production environment. A better idea is to use a logging framework such as `java.util.logging` or `log4j`. These can be configured to dump output to the console, to a file, a DB, a webservice ...

Keep in mind that just becuase you can't see the output it doesn't mean that no work is being done at runtime. The JVM still has to create a String to pass to system.out (or a log statement) which can take a fair bit of memory/CPU for large/complex objects like collections.

Answer (score 0):

Sysout statements access a synchronized, shared resource, which causes [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) between threads using it. That can prevent [memory consistency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) bugs in multithreaded programs if there is no other code which enforces synchronization. When the sysout statements are removed, any existing memory consistency bugs in the code may surface for the first time.

For an example of this effect, see: [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement).

Answer (score -4):

It's not an object and it doesn't have any memory attached to it so there shouldn't be any effect besides the time to run it and compile it. And of course readability maybe lol

Comment: I'd think that the strings that it's outputting *might* actually take some memory, both in the bytecode and during execution. `System.out.println('does this string actually occupy 0 bytes in memory?');`

Comment: The `System.out.println` will take a String as parameter. This String need memory and it will cost some time to create the String. (-1)

Comment: People downvote answers that they believe are incorrect.  That is the nature of the system.  If that fact is disheartening, then you might not be a good fit here.

Comment: Well I won't ever try to help any one here again that's for sure

Comment: We all get downvotes sometimes, even when we believe we are correct. Don't worry about it, and certainly don't take it as a reason to not offer help!